# PHP cookie and time

Tags: php, cookies

I'm am experimenting with cookies for the first time and I don't think I'm understanding this or my code is doing something loopy. Someone mind helping me get back on the right path?

I keep re reading the php.net help but i think my mind is mush now :/

```
$currentTime = strtotime("now");
$popup_exp = strtotime("+1 hour");

if (!isset($_COOKIE['popup_timer'])) : //does cookie exists? if not, make it
    setcookie("popup_timer", $currentTime);
endif;
if( ($popup_exp > $_COOKIE['popup_timer']) ): 
    //show my popup
endif;
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying, what do you expect, or whats going wrong?

Comment: Sorry thought that was obvious, my mind is numb! .. Goal: on load the cookie is created so then it doesn't do anything. Pop up shows. Next time user views site within same hour the site will hide the popup (goal). I can get the time and all that but cannot get this to hide properly, or at all actually

Comment: +1 Ryan for being thoughtful of user experience.

Comment: haha thanks, I try to keep the user in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not getting your code quiet well, but as you commented

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['popup_timer'])) {
   //Show popup
   setcookie("popup_timer", '', time()+3600);
}
```

The above will throw a pop up only if the `$_COOKIE` is not set, once it throws the pop up, a cookie will be set with an expiration set to an hour.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone explains the reason for downvote

Comment: I just evened it. To elaborate on your code, the cookie will expire in 3600 seconds (an hour).

Comment: Thanks guys, this works... now I have to figure out why cookies aren't working when the user is logged out with WordPress.. may be the theme I inherited to fix :/ thanks again! At least my original code wasn't too far off the base and I know I have a WP issue :)

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth Download [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/) plugin, will help you a lot in debugging/development and you welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You should compare your current time with the time stored in the cookie, like this

```
$currentTime = strtotime('now');

if (!isset($_COOKIE['popup_timer'])) {
    setcookie('popup_timer', $currentTime);
} else {
    if ($currentTime > $_COOKIE['popup_timer'] + 60 * 60) {
        // If an hour has passed since cookie creation
        // show your popup
    }
}
```

Comment: When the user visits the website for the first time, no cookie is set and the popup will not show up, which is not intended.